# Chromedriver - unknown error: version info not a dictionary when runnings test via teamcity

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following error when running my tests via teamcity. I am trying to fire up chrome and run tests on a build agent which is a windows server 2008 machine. When the tests are run, multiple instances of chromedriver are fired up (i can see them in task manager) which eventually maxes out CPU/Memory. The browser is not started at all. I then get tests failing with the below error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: version info not a dictionary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236900,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1012
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 846
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 814
```

My setup looks like this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();                
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
_driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver", options);
```

I have looked around for solutions and people have generally got it to work by updating Chrome and chrome driver. I updated my setup to be the below but i still get the same issue

- I am using Chrome version 29
- Chromedriver version 2.7 and have also tried 2.8
- My .Net binding are version 2.3.3
- Specflow version 1.91

Works absolutely fine on my local machine though.

Comment: i'm curious, is there a reason you are using `--start-maximized` vs `driver.manage().window().maximize()`?

Comment: I have recently started looking at this codebase, but I think that used to initially work for IE and FF, but not for chrome. --start-maximized was the only way to get it to work with chromedriver. This was eventually fixed as a bug but we haven't changed it yet

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping all the build agent services then start the build agent from the bat file in the teamcity buildagent folder. Then run the tests and see if that works. If it works I tell you how to set it up like my teamcity server (my chrome driver works).